# Comparar hora en formato java.sql.Time con hora actual

Tags: java, sql-server

Tengo un método recoge una hora de una BD Sql Server en formato java.sql.Time (devuelve solo la hora en formato hh:mm:ss, sin la fecha) y quiero compararla con la hora actual.
¿Como puedo declarar la hora actual en ese mismo formato?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para compara la hora tiene que utilizar el método `toLocalTime()` de la clase  `java.sql.Time` para convertir el objeto a la clase `LocalTime` y realizar comparaciones,te muestro un ejemplo de cómo realizarlo con java 8+:

```
import java.sql.Time;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.Date;

public class CompararHoras {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();
        // Hora que obtendrías de la base de datos.
        Time time = new Time(date.getTime());
        //Utilizamos el método  toLocalTime() para convertir el objeto a LocalTime
        LocalTime horaDB = time.toLocalTime();
        // Hora actual para realizar las comparaciones
        LocalTime horaActual = LocalTime.now();

        System.out.println(horaDB.isAfter(horaActual)); //true
        System.out.println(horaDB.isBefore(horaActual)); //false
        System.out.println(horaDB.getHour() == horaActual.getHour()); //true
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar la clase **SimpleDateFormat**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String horaActual = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    System.out.println(horaActual);
}
```

Eso te dará el formato que deseas: `12:01:39`

Espero que sirva de ayuda :)

Comment: Gracias, pero no puedo comparar un String con una hora en formato java.Sql.Time y si paso la hora Time a String, tampoco puedo compararlos porque dejan de ser horas. @pablohs1986

Comment: @Luis, sin ver todo el código igual no acierto al 100%, pero ¿y si pasas el String a java.Sql.Time?

`java.sql.Date horaEnSql = null;`
 `horaEnSql = horaEnSql.valueOf(horaActual);`

Entiendo que de esa forma ya deberías poder comparar ambos valores.

Comment: @pabloha1986 Algo no va bien.  horaEnSql = horaEnSql.valueOf(horaActual) me devuelve:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException. ¿Otra idea?

Comment: Perdona, @Luis, antes te propuse eso sin llegar a poder probarlo. La propuesta de Roberto sí que funciona.